# how to programmatically reorder items within a UIStackView in IOS?

Tags: ios, uistackview

How can one programmatically reorder items within a UIStackView in IOS?

(i.e. I can not see a function at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015256-CH1-SW30 to cover this)???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

surely you can use a combination of

```
removeArrangedSubview(_:)
insertArrangedSubview(_:atIndex:)
```

to reorder your views?

Comment: do you know offhand if that would give a "flicker" from an UI perspective?  e.g. the uiView might appear somewhere else on the screen for a fraction of a second and then jump back into the stackview?  I should try it...

Comment: it shouldnt, since all the operations of removing and adding will happen before the layout is refreshed, so all changes will appear at once on the next drawing cycle (if you dont do something strange)

Comment: @Greg I've waited every day for the past 484 days to hear back from you! I can't keep silent any more

Comment: @GregHilston hahaha

Answer (score 41):

When adding a view to a parent view, it is automatically removed from it's old parent view.

This is the same with `arrangedView`, so you only need to use `insertArrangedSubview(_:atIndex:)` and `addArrangedSubview()`.

Using `removeArrangedSubview()` is not needed.