# UIStackView layout direction

Tags: ios, uistackview

How to change direction of views by one command in UIStackView? For example, I have: View1, View2, View3 horizontally distributed and I want them to be View3, View2, View1 also horizontally distributed

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible in one command, but simply remove all subviews and re-add all subviews in reverse order (but last one if you want to optimize)

```
removeArrangedSubview(_:)
insertArrangedSubview(_:atIndex:)
```

As stated [how to programmatically reorder items within a UIStackView in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717460/how-to-programmatically-reorder-items-within-a-uistackview-in-ios)